# SWRevealViewController not working on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I use SWRevealViewController as the menu in my App. Since today the App is only available for the iPhone. Now I want to make it ready for the iPad but there's a problem (look at the pictures. The first one shows the App on an iPhone (looks normal), the second on an iPad (looks quite different)).

[image: My App on an iPhone]

[image: on iPad]

Why is white on the iPad?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself.

For the menu you use a tableView(Controller). In the class of the tableView or tableViewController you need to add the following function:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

- You need the override when you use a UITableViewController
- If you use a static TableViewController in storyboard as the menuTableViewController and do not have a class for it, just generate a class and delete all code of it and add the function from above. Then add the class to the MenuTableViewController in storyboard.